# $.each not looping through all the object coming in ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, each

I am getting 3 objects from an AJAX response in `console.log()`. However, only one data is being displayed as an output in the website.

I have tried using `$.each` with the response coming from AJAX but it only shows the data from one object. I want data of all three objects to be displayed in the website.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/process/archiveFull1.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    id: 2018,
  },
  success: function(response) {
    if (typeof(response) != 'object') {
      response = $.parseJSON(response);
    }

    if (response.status.status == true) {
      $.each(response.body, function(key, value) {
        html_option = "<div class='carousel-inner'><div class='carousel-item active'><div class='top-with-controls-archive text-center'>" + value.id + "</h4></div><div class='body-archive'><div class='row py-2'><div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6'><a href='" + value.added_date + "'><img src='" + value.image + "' class='img-fluid'></a></div></div></div>";
      });
      $('#wrap').html(html_option);
    }
  }
});
```

**Edit:** Here is the response I am receiving [image: Here]

Comment: Please take care to format the code in your questions so that it's readable. I've edited it for you

Comment: With regard to the question, can you show us exactly what the content of `response` looks like

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan While adding question I was not able to do ctrl+k.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have added the response I am receiving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the `html` variable each time through the loop, so at the end it just contains the output for the last object. You need to concatenate rather than replace.

```
    if (response.status.status == true) {
      var html_option = '';
      $.each(response.body, function(key, value) {
        html_option += "<div class='carousel-inner'><div class='carousel-item active'><div class='top-with-controls-archive text-center'>" + value.id + "</h4></div><div class='body-archive'><div class='row py-2'><div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6'><a href='" + value.added_date + "'><img src='" + value.image + "' class='img-fluid'></a></div></div></div>";
      });
      $('#wrap').html(html_option);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the content of the response shown in your console snapshot, it's an array of objects. As such you need to loop through them, and append the new HTML within in each iteration of that loop. Currently you are over-writing the previous value each time. Try this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/process/archiveFull1.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    id: 2018,
  },
  success: function(response) {
    if (typeof(response) != 'object') {
      response = $.parseJSON(response);
    }

    var html = response.map(function(obj) {
      return "<div class='carousel-inner'><div class='carousel-item active'><div class='top-with-controls-archive text-center'>" + obj.id + "</h4></div><div class='body-archive'><div class='row py-2'><div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6'><a href='" + obj.added_date + "'><img src='" + obj.image + "' class='img-fluid'></a></div></div></div>";
    });
    $('#wrap').html(html);
  }
});
```

Note that there does not appear to be any `body` or `status` properties in the response you've shown so ensure the response is coming back as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in this line of code.

```
 html_option = "<div class='carousel-inner'>..........................
```

What you are doing is that you are storing value in the html_option during 1st iteration and then replacing it with values of 2nd iterations and then with values of 3rd iteration. So at last your html_option contains only one set of values.

You should replace the above code with

```
html_option += "<div class='carousel-inner'>..........................
```

The "+=" adds each set of values to html_option without replacing previous one.

Or you could use append. http://api.jquery.com/append/